# Error download file in mobile browser (android os) auto convert to .zip?

Tags: php, android

When i using link `<a href="test.apk">download</a>` is result download OK

But when I using form submit is error

This is code:

```
<a href="download.php">download</a>
```

in `download.php` i using code:

```
...
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='test.apk';" );
    readfile('test.apk');
...
```

When click on download is from `test.apk` auto convert to `test.zip` (I using android 2.3), How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error is occured for mime type :
to rectify this error add this code in .htaccess

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive
```